# Como devolver dos objetos java distintos en una funcion?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando crear un metodo para simplificar codigo y no tener que repetir codigo, por lo cual quiero declarar un metodo conexion en java el cual solo conecta con la base de datos el tema es que necesito la variable conexion y sentencia para seguir con otros metodos, paso el codigo por si alguien puede decirme si esto puede hacerse

```
    public Statement Connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
        Statement sentencia= conexion.createStatement();
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Connection, Statement>(conexion, sentencia);
        
        
    } 
    public void Close(){

        conexion.close();
    }
   
    public Statement Query(String tabla, String campo){
        try{
            Statement sentencia2= Connect();
            
            String sql="SELECT "+campo+" FROM "+tabla;
            ResultSet resul=sentencia2.executeQuery((sql));
            while(resul.next()){
                System.out.printf(" %s, %s, %g, %n",
                resul.getString(1),
                resul.getString(2),
                resul.getDouble(3));
            }
    
            resul.close();
            sentencia2.close();
            
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SQLException b){
            b.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generalmente las conexiones se gestionan con un "pool", pero en este caso podrías crear una clase que tenga dos propiedades, connection y statement.

Comment: No se entiende mucho para que quieres mantener viva la conexión e incluso el statement ¿? ¿Pretendes seguir modificando esos datos en otro contexto?